Object does not follow entire curve for follow path constraint
I am trying to make an object follow a bezier curve I made with the follow path constraint, but when I add the constraint the object starts about halfway down the curve, adjusting the offsets forward makes it travel along the curve well, but backwards and the object just goes straight back and does not follow the curve at all.
The name of the object i am trying to get to follow the curve is f35c-airframe, in the f35 collection.
Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAHa24OKId018tQcxcBIJpVyWwyzo4Bi/view?usp=sharing

Please do not use external links to provide information. Without seeing the file I would suspect your object is offset from the center?

Select the airplane, put the Offset at 0, put the Influence at 1 and press AltG to reset the object location. Select the curve, in the N panel of the Graph Editor remove the Generator modifier and instead keyframe the Path Animation > Evaluation Time value of the curve, also note that the object will be at the start of the curve but as another segment of the curve is overlapping it looks like it is not the start.

Hello, thanks for the feedback and sorry for a late response, I tried your method to no avail but I think the solution is much simpler, After some more troubleshooting I have noticed that when I separate the curve into 2 separate curves at the spot where it goes up steep, the follow path constraint works along both curves separately but as soon as I join them and connect them it only works on the second half.
